# JS - variable scope and initilizing inside function

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why the following code doesn't work.

```
var test=null;
(function(){
 var Class=...
 test=new Class();
})();
test.doSomething();// ERROR test is null
```

As I know if I don't declare variable using var than js must find the variable outside current scope (function). Please, say what I'm doin wrong.

**EDIT**
The full code:

```
  var Application=null;
    require(["Aqua","$"],function(Aqua,$){
        var Class = Aqua.Application.extend();
        Application = new Class();
    }); 
Application.do("aaa");//Application is null
```

but the following works

```
  var Application=null;
    require(["Aqua","$"],function(Aqua,$){
        var Class = Aqua.Application.extend();
        Application = new Class();
        Application.do("aaa");
    });
```

Comment: @Jonast92 That's an IIFE though. *Immediately Invoked*. aka Synchrnous.

Comment: @Jonast92 False, just totally wrong.

Comment: It works for me; could you post the entire code?

Comment: In any case, [Could Not Reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/f5512r8b/)

Comment: agreed... The error are you certain it is getting to the variable assignment last line?

Comment: @Scimonster I edited

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol I edited

Comment: @PashaTurok Now you've changed from an IIFE to an asynchronous callback, that changes everything.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Could you explain why it changes? I do call require method that must be executed before Application.do(). I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require is an asynchronous dependency library and as such the bottom line `Application.do("aaa");` is not in the callback.  That bottom line is called before the require.js callback with the `Application = new Class();` part has run.

You have solved it in your bottom example for this very reason.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I know that require is asynchronous library - it loads modules asynchronously. But! We do call method require(). So It must be executed first. Please,explain.

Comment: You call it first, but that does not mean it has completed executing, it can happen in parallel.  It has to go get resources asynchronously, via AJAX.  More can be learned by reading about AJAX and how that works or the JavaScript event loop approach.  The callback code waits on the JavaScript execution stack until Javascript completes running actively on say the lines below the require function call like your `Application.do("aaa");`.  The key is that require.js is using those (AJAX and event loop) facilities under the covers to do things in 'parallel'.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I thought that require() works other way. Now I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are doing something wrong in the ellipsed part?

This works fine for me:

```
var test=null;
(function () {
    var Class = function () {
        this.doSomething = function () { console.log('hey'); }
    };
    test = new Class();
})();
test.doSomething();// prints hey
```

Notice you need to add the `this` since it is a class and you are using `new`